# Find/write functions in a language agnostic way?

Tags: function, language-agnostic

EDIT (complete rewrite): Consider the function that takes two inputs and adds the sine of the first to the cosine of the second (and assumes the arguments are in radians). Here it is in a few languages

```
$f = sub {sin($_[0])+cos($_[1])}; # Perl 
f = Sin[#1]+Cos[#2] &; # Mathematica 
def f(x,y) sin(x)+cos(y) end; # Ruby
```

(minor note: I've written it as a pure function in Perl and 
Mathematica, but wasn't sure how to do this Ruby).

My question: surely someone has written a language/format/convention 
that will take:

```
x,y:sin(x)+cos(y)
```

and convert it to any of the three forms above on request.

Ideally, it could do the conversion backwards as well, but that's a 
lot more difficult.

So, what is that language/format/convention?

To emphasize, I'm referring to simple functions here, not complicated 
procedures, and am assuming the target languages define basic 
functions like sin(), cos(), atan(), etc.

I've looked at MathML, TeX, and even MathType, but none of them seem 
quite designed for this.

My goal is to create a library of astronomy functions that anyone can use without having to port them by hand. Example:

$\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (\text{dec}) \sin (\text{lat})-\cos (\text{dec}) \cos (\text{lat}) \sin (\text{d1}+\text{lon}-\text{ra})}{\sqrt{(\cos (\text{dec}) \sin (\text{lat}) \sin (\text{d1}+\text{lon}-\text{ra})+\sin (\text{dec}) \cos (\text{lat}))^2+\cos ^2(\text{dec}) \cos ^2(\text{d1}+\text{lon}-\text{ra})}}\right)$

There's nothing inherently difficult about computing this function, but, even using search/replace, it would be ugly to convert this from one language to another.

Comment: Am I the only one seeing raw TeX here? It should have converted?

Comment: It looks like [TeX is not enabled on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252282/theres-seriously-no-reason-why-latex-markup-via-mathjax-shouldnt-be-enabled-on/252286#252286).

Comment: I'll just leave it like that to show how complex it is :P

Answer (score 1):

Due to the difference in semantics and syntax between the various languages you've listed (especially language "etc"), you can't write useful functions in a general way that allows them to be used unchanged in more than one target language.

Your best chance at this would be to pick one language to define your functions in.  We'll call this the *source language*.  Then write transpilers to translate from the source language to each target language.  Your source language will probably be one of your own invention; it will have to be carefully limited to only those semantics which can be represented in each of the supported target languages.

For the use case you present (simple functions), I don't think you'll find that anyone has done this.  It's a great deal of work for not that great a benefit, when compared to simply translating the functions by hand into each target language.

Comment: Clarified my question to indicate I'm looking for more of a "meta language"

Comment: @barrycarter I've added a paragraph explaining why you probably won't find that anyone has done this.

Comment: Added example of "simple" formula that is nonetheless long and ugly.

Comment: @barrycarter I'm pretty sure you and I aren't communicating well.  I'll bet we could clear up our misunderstanding in no time in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44914/ruby-sometimes-on-rails), if you want.